# React and Redux : How to show the action.type on the Components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i want to be able to show status of the action.type in the component when i trigger it : it's for showing if an action has been passed succesfully or not(when catch triggered).
Have you an idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
*emphasized text*someAction.js
when a action will be called dispatch the follwing line. 



    const someActionToBeCalledFromComponent = (parameters) => async(dispatch) => {
      try {
        dispatch({
          type: SOME_ACTION_HAS_CALLED_SUCCESSFULLY
        });
        //do your stufs 
      } catch (error) {
        //do your stufs
      }
    }

    <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->




})
      //do your stuffs . 
    }
    catch(error) { 
      //do your stufs here. 
    }
    }

<!-- end snippet -->



Now in reducer catch the action type 



    const someReducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {

          case: SOME_ACTION_HAS_CALLED_SUCCESSFULLY
          return {
            status_of_the_action_type: true
          }

          //other cases goes here
          default: return state
        }





Now keep the reducer in a state and use it in typical way of redux.
```

Comment: Hi, actually i want to be able to display the action.type in my component, it to evaluate the type who's triggered.
For example : in my component i want to console.log(MyReduxAction.action.type)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it through your console , and have access to the

action inside your component, you could simply trigger a console.log(action.type) inside it.